# Under what circumstances compact $\iff$ closed and bounded

Tags: general-topology, compactness

It is known in $\mathbb R^n$ we have compact $\iff$ closed and bounded. But someone once told me that this is not true in general. Now I am wondering what is needed for this to be true?

First, for "compact", "closed", "bounded" to be meaningful, the space must have a metric. It follows from this that one direction, namely "compact$\implies$bounded and closed" (prop 1.4.2 in Conway's *A Course in Point Set Topology*), holds.

**Questions:**

(1) What property of the metric space is needed for the converse to be true? (I mean what is needed for every closed and bounded subset to be compact?)

(2) Is there an example such that closed and bounded $\nRightarrow$ compact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me note you don't need a metric to talk about a subset of a topological space being closed or compact.

The Heine-Borel Theorem states that a subset of an euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Meanwhile a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded.

As an example imagine an infinite discrete space. It is trivially closed and also bounded, but not compact. It is also not complete and not totally bounded.

It turns out a subset of a euclidean space is bounded if and only if it is totally bounded, and complete if and only if closed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... I understand (2) now. But for (1) actually I wanted to ask what is needed for every closed and bounded subset of the space to be compact. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: @trisct you would need that closed and bounded implies complete and totally bounded. If the space is complete then closed is always going to imply complete (because every Cauchy sequence will have a Cauchy subsequence that converges necessarily to a point INSIDE the set). For bounded to imply totally bounded I guess it would suffice for the metric to have a property akin of being [doubling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space)

Comment: Just noted the part in parenthesis in my comment is not quite right, it should just say: (because every Cauchy sequence converges to a point that is necessarily inside the set)

Comment: @Anguepa I'm guessing, he was looking for missing condition(s) (say $C$) which ALONG with closed and boundedness would imply compactness. That is, $S$ is closed, bounded, <missing condition, property, etc> $C \Rightarrow S$ is compact, I had the same question, would appreciate it really if you'd reply.

Answer (score 0):

1) If the metric space is complete and totally bounded.

2) Many examples including discrete metric.